# image size in cocos2d v3.3 compare to v3.0

Tags: image, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

In the 3.0 cocos2d version on ipad retina (in portrait mode) an image of size 1536 × 2048 put on a scene was full screen. In the v3.3 the same image is twice the screen. What can I do to correct this. I precise that this image has a -ipadhd suffix.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem was Spritebuilder as my project doesn't use it. So I fixed the issue in commenting :

```
//[CCBReader configureCCFileUtils];
```

in the appDelegate.m